# Difference b/w IN and INTO

Tags: prepositions

As he was feeling very thirsty /after a long journey,/he went into a bar/ and ordered a cool drink.
What is difference b/w in bar and into bar .

Comment: [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/in-to-or-into) to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

Richard Nordquist, Ph.D., provides a detailed explanation [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/inandintogloss.htm), but for sheer brevity and clarity, it would be hard to beat [this](http://languagelearningbase.com/10827/whats-difference-between-worlds-into-when-each-one-questions) answer from languagelearningbase.com:

> The difference between in and into is whether or not there is
>   movement. Into is used when something or someone is going or being put
>   into another location. In is used to describe where someone or
>   something already is.
>
> Ex:  She is in the room. She walked into the room.
>
> The toy is in the box. The boy put the toy into the box.
>
> In American English, we sometimes use the two prepositions
>   interchangeably. Ex: She got in the car. She got into the car.  Both
>   are acceptable.

The one thing that I might add is that examples of interchangeability (considered colloquial no more than a generation ago) usually involve non-concrete verb choices (get, put, etc.). These were (and are still) commonly employed in imperative commands, where neither the manner of action nor the correctness of grammar seem particularly relevant.

People are becoming increasingly comfortable with using these imperative forms in a more subjunctive sense (e.g., 'Get on the bus') but appear to be less comfortable omitting 'to' when using a phrase that is not typically associated with imperative statements.  Compare the following usages on [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got%20onto%20the%20bus%2C%20got%20on%20the%20bus%2C%20stepped%20on%20the%20bus%2C%20stepped%20onto%20the%20bus&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15%3E&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20onto%20the%20bus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20on%20the%20bus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstepped%20on%20the%20bus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstepped%20onto%20the%20bus%3B%2Cc0), where 'stepped onto the bus' clearly outranks 'stepped on the bus'.